# SyntaxError Unexpected token when creating Nestjs backend for my angular frontend

Tags: angular, nestjs, nrwl-nx

I'm trying to make a backend project for my angular frontend in my monorepo, but I get an error when using the "nest new backendproject --strict" command:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '('
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1116:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1164:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1089:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:73:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ycrbo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@nestjs\cli\node_modules\glob\node_modules\minimatch\dist\cjs\index.js:9:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1200:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
```

I tried uninstalling and installing nestjs and node, as that was what's given as a solution, but that didn't work. I also have the latest versions. I also tried another solution on stackoverflow, where the babel config was edited, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Type of monorepo?

Comment: @AndrewAllen nx monorepo

Comment: Nx has a nest [plugin](https://nx.dev/packages/nest), `nx g @nx/nest:app backendproject`

Comment: @AndrewAllen @nx/nest package wasn't installed correctly, so I installed it and this fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are mentioning that you already have a monorepo and your question is tagged with [nrwl-nx](/questions/tagged/nrwl-nx) then you shouldn't create a nest application using the nest cli. This is now the functionality of Nx.

First of all you need to add nx/nest package

```bash
npm install -D @nx/nest
```

Then generate the application using the nx cli

```bash
nx g @nx/nest:app backend-project
```

You can find more information about it [here](https://nx.dev/packages/nest)